# Return value using String result=Command.ExecuteScalar() error occurs when result returns null

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, database

I want to fetch 1st row 1st cell value from database it works well with below code . But when there is no result found it throws Exception.

How to handle with `DBNull` .
Should i change my query ? which return some value if theirs no record ?

*System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

**Code:**

```
    public string absentDayNo(DateTime sdate, DateTime edate, string idemp)
    { 
       string result="0";
       string myQuery="select COUNT(idemp_atd) absentDayNo from td_atd where ";
       myQuery +=" absentdate_atd between '"+sdate+"' and '"+edate+" ";
       myQuery +=" and idemp_atd='"+idemp+"' group by idemp_atd ";

       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(myQuery, conn);
       conn.Open();
//System.NullReferenceException occurs when their is no data/result
       string getValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
         if (getValue != null)
         {
            result = getValue.ToString();
         }
         conn.Close();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Where it throws exception ??

Comment: Exception throws `string getValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();`  mean error occurs when their is no result

Comment: btw, that is a **really** bad way to build a query; clear and blatant sql injection hole; there's also an internationalisation issue, and some unnecessary intermediate strings. I hope that isn't how you do sql normally...

Comment: @MarcGravell: Sry for my bad practising habbit , and yes next time i take care of `sqlInjection`, by using parameterize queries

Comment: @Satindersingh as per my edited answer: you can actually solve both issues in one go... just saying...

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There is no need to keep calling `.ToString()` as `getValue` is already a string.

Aside that, this line could possibly be your problem:

```
 string getValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

If there are no rows `.ExecuteScalar` will return `null` so you need to do some checking.

For instance:

```
var firstColumn = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

if (firstColumn != null) {
    result = firstColumn.ToString();
}
```

Comment: thanks this works well, also Naresh Parmar answer worked for my by adding check for string is ""

Comment: or you could use `Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());` - this will give you `String.Empty` if the value is `null`.

Answer (score 22):

If the first cell returned is a `null`, the result in .NET will be `DBNull.Value`

If *no cells are returned*, the result in .NET will be `null`; you cannot call `ToString()` on a `null`. You can of course capture what `ExecuteScalar` returns and process the `null` / `DBNull` / other cases separately.

Since you are grouping etc, you presumably could potentially have more than one group. Frankly I'm not sure `ExecuteScalar` is your best option here...

---

Additional: the sql in the question is bad in many ways:

- sql injection
- internationalization (let's hope the client and server agree on what a date looks like)
- unnecessary concatenation in separate statements

I strongly suggest you parameterize; perhaps with something like "dapper" to make it easy:

```
int count = conn.Query<int>(
  @"select COUNT(idemp_atd) absentDayNo from td_atd
    where absentdate_atd between @sdate and @edate
    and idemp_atd=@idemp group by idemp_atd",
    new {sdate, edate, idemp}).FirstOrDefault();
```

all problems solved, including the "no rows" scenario. The dates are passed as dates (not strings); the injection hole is closed by use of a parameter. You get query-plan re-use as an added bonus, too. The `group by` here is redundant, BTW - if there is only one group (via the equality condition) you might as well just select `COUNT(1)`.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation, 1st time heard about `dapper`, learn new today

Comment: @Satindersingh it is freely available on nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper

Answer (score 9):

Try this one

```
var getValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();    
conn.Close();
return (getValue == null) ? string.Empty : getValue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 7):

Value is not null, but DBNull.Value.

```
object value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if(value == DBNull.Value)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use like the following

```
string result = null;
object value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
 if (value != null)
 {
    result = value.ToString();
 }     
 conn.Close();
return result;
```

Comment: @Satindersingh where did you try? what code did you use? the code in the question does not show this...

Comment: @Satindersingh: No issues... please do not apologize. Its fine if it solves the problem.

Comment: @saravanan: one query out of this topic, how you added adds in you blog, want to add in my http://satindersinght.blogspot.in/2013/04/morelinq-distinctby-how-to-remove.html

Comment: @Satindersingh: Please follow the steps in this link: http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=50288. You will have to register for Adsense with your account and add the appropriate content to the blog.

Answer (score 2):

try this  :

```
 string getValue = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
conn.Close();

return result != null ? result.ToString() : string.Empty;
```

Also, I'd suggest using Parameters in your query, something like (just a suggestion):

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand
{
    Connection = conn,
    CommandType = CommandType.Text,
    CommandText = "select COUNT(idemp_atd) absentDayNo from td_atd where absentdate_atd between @sdate and @edate and idemp_atd=@idemp group by idemp_atd"
};

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sdate", sdate);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@edate", edate);
// etc ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL server isnull function

```
public string absentDayNo(DateTime sdate, DateTime edate, string idemp)
{ 
    string result="0";
    string myQuery="select isnull(COUNT(idemp_atd),0) as absentDayNo from td_atd where ";
    myQuery +=" absentdate_atd between '"+sdate+"' and '"+edate+" ";
    myQuery +=" and idemp_atd='"+idemp+"' group by idemp_atd ";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(myQuery, conn);
    conn.Open();
    //System.NullReferenceException occurs when their is no data/result
    string getValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    if (getValue != null)
    {
        result = getValue.ToString();
    }
    conn.Close();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, if null set 0 or something

```
return command.ExecuteScalar() == DBNull.Value ? 0 : (double)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a advance feature of c#, use that '?.' .
string getValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar()?.ToString();  thants all.

Answer (score -1):

To work with NpgsqlCommand or the standard sqlCommand use:

```
int result = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```